# PDO FetcthAll to JSON null

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm creating a APIRest in Angular and I need to parse PHP results to JSON. I read some answer about this problem, but didn't resolve my problem.

The problem is the `json_encode` return `null`, and i don't know why.

```
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog", "root", "");
$sql = "select * from articles";
$sql = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$json = json_encode($sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

if ($json) {
    echo $json;
} else {
    echo "Error";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Don't know why you use `prepare()` but http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: If a remove prepare() doesn´t return null, return error echo.

Comment: You are not `execute()` ing your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For JSON you need `utf-8` encoded data, thus you have to tell PDO that

```
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog;charset=utf8mb4", "root", "");
$sql = $conexion->query("select * from articles");
echo json_encode($sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

the rest of code makes no sense and should be removed.

Comment: Touché, a "noob" error. Charset=utf8 causes nulls and errors, i add it and resolve. Thanks.